# Do you need to update VLC first before installation?

Tags: command-line, bash, updates, sudo, vlc

I am trying to use commands to update or install VLC on Linux. I am trying to use `sudo apt install vlc` or `sudo apt update vlc` but these commands seem like they are not working.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. "not working" is not a good error description, we cannot help you with that amount of information. Please tell us about your OS details and the complete error message you're receiving. Please don't add this information to the comments, rather edit your question.

Comment: `sudo apt update vlc` is not a valid command, but you do need to run `sudo apt update` (without an argument) before you start a session in apt. You should also run `sudo apt upgrade` to bring your system up-to-date before you attempt to install new software. If you're having problems, please edit your question with the full output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Please copy/paste exactly and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to preserve monospace formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your VLC to be updated more frequently, VLC is also available as a snap package, and the VLC snap package is updated automatically. You can install the VLC snap package from the terminal by running the following command:

```
sudo snap install vlc
```

Otherwise `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` will upgrade the VLC apt package along with other installed apt packages if updates are available.